# ActiveXObject in Angular6 for calc.exe

Tags: angular

I add in my **head** from html this code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    function execProg(progam){
     var prog = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
     prog.run(progam, 0, true);
    }
  </script>
```

Then in my component.ts when I do click in html ->

```
public comprobarUrl = function() {
     this.execProg('Calc');
}
```

If I do this in html is correct, I can open calc.exe with IE, but if I do this in Angular6 I get

```
The object does not accept the property or the 'execProg' method
```

Comment: this is reference to your "function" which are just.. a function without any other properties.. You may have to create `ActiveXObject` object on your function and use this fresh variable to call `execProg` function.

Comment: I want to access a my function inside from <script> in my head with Angular6 ... I can't arrive to my function...

Comment: Remove `this.` and just call `execProg('Calc')`. But honestly, stop using `ActiveXObject`, it's a security nightmare and only works in IE.

Comment: if I remove "this". I get error from IDE because "typescript" don't found function execProg...

Comment: you have to choice, remove the "this" keyword (but you will have typescript error) or store it in window like `window.myFunction = function() {}` then on your typescript `(window as any).myFunction()`

Comment: in my function the component.ts --> (window as any).execProg('Calc'); ???

Comment: yes, but before, instead of declaring pure function, you should do `window.execProg = function(...)`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, can you publish this ? then , do I need the code in head the script from head ?? :S